# Does anybody know any DIY kit with embedded linux suporting C# Mono?

Tags: c#, mono, embedded

I mean something like this:
http://www.globalscaletechnologies.com/p-25-sheevaplug-dev-kit-uk.aspx

My minimal hardware requirement is: Ethernet card

UPDATE:
These days we have cheaper alternative running mono. It's raspberry pi: http://www.raspberrypi.org/ with Soft-float Debian image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow! it seems it's possible to run mono on Sheeva plug !! :)

http://plugcomputer.org/plugwiki/index.php/Running_.Net_and_ASP.Net_applications

Answer (score 1):

If what you are looking for is a small board with an ethernet connection to program in C# maybe that linux and mono are not the best match.

Keeping your C# requirements you can take a look at the .NET Micro Framework witch is going to be [opensourced by Microsoft](http://blogs.msdn.com/netmfteam/) and is available on some boards ARM7 and ARM9 boards (sorry, but already used my hyperlink)

Regards
PFM

Comment: sounds very promising - thanks for info ! I've to take a closer look on it.

Comment: Well, Ubuntu supports ARM too, so mono and linux on embedded devices works.

Comment: I'm not sure where you get the idea that Mono and Linux wouldn't work.  Mono has its linker (<http://www.mono-project.com/Linker>) which can be used to tailer CIL library to only what's needed.  It's more flexible than the .NET Micro Framework.